# Execute command on the same line multiple times with sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I need to highlight every duplicate word in the text with `*` symbol.
For example

```
lol foo lol bar foo bar
```

should be

```
lol foo *lol* bar *foo* *bar*
```

I tried with the following command:

```
echo "lol foo lol bar foo bar" | sed -r -e 's/(\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)([^*]+)(\1)/\1\2*\3*/'
```

It gives me:

```
lol foo *lol* bar foo bar
```

Then I added `g` flag:

```
lol foo *lol* bar foo *bar*
```

But `foo` is not highlighted.
I know that it happens because `sed` [doesn't look behind if the match was found](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-7).

Can I handle it with only `sed`?

Comment: Only `sed` you say... This would require some `sed` wizardry I believe.

Comment: Why not use `awk`? It may solve your problem.

Comment: @Jotne frankly speaking I've got the task to do it with only sed. But in general I was interested if `sed` can execute same command on the one line several times

Comment: So this is school work?

Comment: @Jotne it was work for bash courses, but then I was interested in general solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sed` is not the best tool for this task. It doesn't look-ahead, look-behind and non-greedy quantifiers, but give a try to the following command:

```
sed -r -e ':a ; s/\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b(.*) (\1)( |$)/\1\2 *\3* / ; ta'
```

It uses conditional branching to execute the substitution command until it fails. Also, you cannot check `([^*]+)` because for second round it has to traverse some `*` of the first substitution, your option is a greedy `.*`. And last, you cannot match `(\1)` only because it would match the first string `lol` again and again. You need some context like surrounded by spaces or end of line.

The command yields:

```
lol foo *lol* bar *foo* *bar*
```

---

**UPDATE**: An improvement provided by [potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong) in comments:

```
sed -r ':a;s/\b(([[:alpha:]]+)\s.*\s)\2\b/\1*\2*/;ta' file
```

Comment: @Birei yes, this is magic, it works for me! 
could you please explain what `a` and `ta` commands do in this case?

Comment: A slight improvement (as this solution might introduce an extra space at the end of the line when the last word is a repetition) is: `sed -r ':a;s/\b(([[:alpha:]]+)\s.*\s)\2\b/\1*\2*/;ta' file` . N.B. If you insert the `l0` command just before the `ta` command, you get to see sed do its magic.

Comment: @Dany: It's the `goto` statement of many programming languages, but conditional. `:a` is the label and `ta` means: **go to label "a" if last substitution command succeed**.

Comment: @potong: Thanks. I've updated the answer to add your improved version.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (a[$i]++>=1) printf "*%s* ",$i; else printf "%s ",$i; print ""}' file
lol foo *lol* bar *foo* *bar*
```